# An incomprehensible line in the output from hex rays

Tags: hexrays

```
v5 = (*(int (__cdecl **)(int))((char *)&etext + 1))(a1);
```

Please explain me what does this line mean (if possible, please write from what it was compiled from (language - c))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a convoluted function call via function pointers.

```
(*(int (__cdecl **)(int))
```

casts a given number to a pointer to a function pointer (note the `**` so second degree function pointer) and dereferences it so you end up with a regular function pointer. The calling convention in use being `cdecl`. The target function would look like:

```
int __cdecl do_something(int some_arg) { ... }
```

The number being cast and dereferenced then is the address of `etext` plus 1. So at `etext + 1` is an address, that points to another address that points to a function.

That function then is called with `a5` as the argument, storing the return value in v5.

If I had to make up a C snippet, it would be something like this, the last line being what you posted:

```
typedef int (_cdecl *fptr2)(int);    //first degree function pointer typedef
typedef int (_cdecl **fptr1)(int);   //second degree function pointer typedef

int _cdecl do_something(int arg)
{
    return arg+5;
}

void main()
{
    struct
    {
        char unused;             //this is for the etext + 1
        fptr2 pp_func;           //stores a fptr to a fptr
    } etext;

    fptr1 func = &do_something;  //first degree function pointer
    etext.pp_func = &func;       //second degree function pointer
    (*etext.pp_func)(1337);      //the actual call and the equivalent of your line
}
```

A more real-world example would probably be `etext+1` storing a pointer to a list of function pointers. Outside of that I rarely see second degree function pointers.